# Adding data to nested model (phoenix-framework)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So, I have model order_items and order_attributes. And order_attributes model is nested to order_items.

```
schema "order_attributes" do
 belongs_to :order_item, Myapp.OrderItem
 belongs_to :attribute, Myapp.Attribute
 timestamps
end

schema "order_items" do
 field :quantity, :integer, default: 1
 belongs_to :order, Myapp.Order
 belongs_to :food, Myapp.Food
 has_many :order_attributes, Myapp.OrderAttribute
 timestamps
end
```

I am struggling adding data to model order_attributes. To add data to order_item, I use hidden input to insert data rather than using new action. Like below.

```
<%= hidden_input f, :food_id, value: @chicken_id %>
```

So when you click menu item, it insert data to model order_items through this hidden input. Like order_items, I want to insert data to order_attributes model through hidden input. So I made

```
   <%= inputs_for f, :order_attributes, fn of -> %>
   <%= hidden_input of, :attribute_id, value: 1 %>
   <%= hidden_input of, :order_item_id, value: @order_item_id %>
   <% end %>
```

but this code is not working.... how should I fix this? can I use hidden input to insert data to nested model?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I got the question correctly but I think you should use `inputs_for` for this. More info can be found [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#inputs_for/4)

Comment: Give us some more information why "this code is not working." Are you seeing an error? Are the attributes simply not persisted?

Comment: I mean that data doesnt insert to order_attributes model table.. there is no error.